# Java : Finding String literals in String

Tags: java, regex, string, stack

Lets say i have a string :

`look_up_check('US_POPULATION','('POPULATION' = 3844829) and ('CITY' = 'Los Angeles')')`

now from this, i have to find : `'US_POPULATION' , 'POPULATION', 'CITY'  , 'Los Angeles'` .

I have tried using stack based approach but not up to the mark. Can i use **regex** or any other approach?.

Comment: The `'` in your input string are not balanced (there is a odd number of them). So the second string is actually `'('`

Comment: Ohh...Let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a regex-less solution.

The stuff inside the quotes of your string is currently:

```
US_POPULATION
(
 = 3844829) and (
 = 
)
```

which is not what you want. To get the strings you want, the quotes must be arranged this way:

```
look_up_check('US_POPULATION',('POPULATION' = 3844829) and ('CITY' = 'Los Angeles'))
```

Solution:

```
public static List<String> findStuffInQuotes(String s) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean insideQuotes = false;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '\'') {
            insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            if (!insideQuotes) {
                list.add(sb.toString());
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
        } else if (insideQuotes) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    list.add(sb.toString());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: that's fine. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for example :

```
String str = "look_up_check('US_POPULATION','('POPULATION' = 3844829) and ('CITY' = 'Los Angeles')')";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'[\\w\\s]+'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Outputs**

```
'US_POPULATION'
'POPULATION'
'CITY'
'Los Angeles'
```

---

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BzWFHf/1)

Comment: This makes some heavy assumptions about the content of a string literal.

Comment: I ended up implementing like this: https://regex101.com/r/atL7z4/1   Any suggestions?

Comment: can you gives me an example @Henry what did you mean?

Comment: @YCF_L it would for example not work for this `'Washington, D.C.'`. Depends on the context if it is a problem or not.

Comment: mmm, correct in this case the OP can use `'[\w\s.,]+'` instead, i think the OP have only a short group of separator so he can include all what he need :)

Comment: @YCF_L . yeah i converted to this : '[\w\s_ .,!@#$%^&*=|]+' . If i want to delete all remaining quotes from string , any approach suggested?

Comment: Yes i tried. One exception though->  ', '  (match 5) https://regex101.com/r/BzWFHf/2

Comment: You can use the following regex to find strings (also empty ones) enclosed in single quotes: ```'[^']*?'```
The magic here is done by the ? which tells the * to match lazy instead of greedy. If you want to get rid of the quotes, use a group: ```'([^']*?)'``` and get this from the matcher instead of the whole match using ```matcher.group(1)```

Comment: thank you @MichaelA.Schaffrath i tried to do your regex but it fail it shows me wrong values :(

Comment: The regex works like intended - it collects string literals delimited by the single quote character. But the reference-string provided by @Bond is not well formed to meet the requirements because it embeds strings in other strings without escaping the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

For having something more robust than regex and handwritten lexical analyzers, you can use a Flex-like tool to create one. I created a simple parser in JFlex+CUP (http://jflex.de/manual.html, http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/install.php) that parses the text you provided.

First, you need to create the .flex file that will describe the rules to generating tokens:

```
import java_cup.runtime.*;
import java.util.*;

%%
%unicode
%class LexicalAnalyzer
%line
%column
%cup

/*numbers*/
number      = ([1-9][0-9]*| 0)([.][0-9]+ )?([eE]([+]|[-])?[0-9]+)?
digit       = [0-9]
underscore = [_]


identifier = {identifier5} ( [.] {identifier5} )*

identifier2 = {letter} ({letter}|{digit}|{underscore})*
identifier3 = {digit} ({letter}|{digit}|{underscore})+
identifier4 = {underscore} ({letter}|{digit}|{underscore})+
identifier5     = {identifier2} | {identifier3} | {identifier4}
letter      = {lowercase} | {uppercase}
lowercase   = [a-z]
uppercase   = [A-Z]
inputchar   = [^\r\n]

/*Comments*/
lineterminator  = \r | \n | \r\n
simplecomment   = "//" {inputchar}* {lineterminator}
blockcomment    = "/*" ( [^*]* | "*"+ [^/*] )* "*"+ "/" 


%{

private void error(){
    System.err.print("Sintax error on line " + (yyline+1));
    System.err.println(". Unrecognizable token: \"" + yytext() + "\"");
    //System.exit(1);
}

private Symbol processToken(int type, Object value) {
    System.out.println("Type: " + type);
        System.out.println("Value: " + value );
        return new Symbol(type);
}

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

%}

%state STRING
%state END

%%

<YYINITIAL> {
    /* string literals */

    [']        {str.setLength(0);yybegin(STRING);}

        "and" { return processToken( sym.AND , yytext()); }



    /* number literals */
    {number} { return processToken(sym.NUMBER , yytext()); }

    /* identifiers */


    {identifier} { return processToken( sym.IDENTIFIER , yytext()); }


    "("    { return processToken( sym.OPENP , yytext()); }
    ")"    { return processToken( sym.CLOSEP , yytext()); }
    "="  { return processToken(sym.EQUALS , yytext());  }
    ","  { return processToken(sym.COMMA , yytext());  }
    "+"  { return processToken(sym.OP , yytext());  }
    "-"  { return processToken(sym.OP , yytext());  }
    "*"  { return processToken(sym.OP , yytext());  }
    "/"  { return processToken(sym.OP , yytext());    }


    // whitespace and comments
    {simplecomment} {/* Do nothing */}
    {blockcomment}  {} 
    " "|\t|\n|  {lineterminator}    {/* Do nothing */}
        .               {error();}
    //.             { /*error!*/ } 
}



/* literais string */
<STRING> {
    [']              { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return processToken( sym.STRING , str.toString()); } 
    \\t             { str.append('\t'); }
    \\n             { str.append('\n'); }
    \\r             { str.append('\r'); }
    \\\"            { str.append('\"'); }
    \\\\            { str.append('\\'); }
    \\[']           { str.append('\''); }
    \\[0-9][0-9][0-9] 
    {
        String s = yytext().substring(1);
        s = "" + ((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
        str.append( s );
    }
    [^\n\r\'\\\t]+    { str.append( yytext() ); }
    .               { /* malformed string */}
}

<END>{
    \n  {}
    .   {}
}
```

Then, you need to compile this parser specification with the JFlex.jar

```
java -jar JFlex.jar lexical.flex
```

It will create a source file named "LexicalAnalyzer.java" that you can use to break a string into tokens according to your specification.

```
public class Parser {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String str = "look_up_check('US POPULATION', ( 'POPULATION' = 3844829 ) and ('CITY' = 'Los Angeles'))";

    ByteArrayInputStream buff = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());

    LexicalAnalyzer l = new LexicalAnalyzer(buff);

    Symbol s = l.next_token();

    while(s.sym != sym.EOF){
        s = l.next_token();
    }

    }

}
```

Producing the output:

```
Type: 5
Value: look_up_check
Type: 3
Value: (
Type: 1
Value: US POPULATION
Type: 9
Value: ,
Type: 3
Value: (
Type: 1
Value: POPULATION
Type: 8
Value: =
Type: 7
Value: 3844829
Type: 4
Value: )
Type: 2
Value: and
Type: 3
Value: (
Type: 1
Value: CITY
Type: 8
Value: =
Type: 1
Value: Los Angeles
Type: 4
Value: )
Type: 4
Value: )
```

**Edit:** the sym.java class

```
public class sym {
    public static int STRING = 1;
    public static int AND = 2;
    public static int OPENP = 3;
    public static int CLOSEP = 4;
    public static int IDENTIFIER = 5;
    public static int OP = 6;
    public static int NUMBER = 7;
    public static int EQUALS = 8;
    public static int COMMA = 9;
    public static int EOF = 10;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit over-engineered?

Comment: @Henry

It's easier than it seems, and knowing how to write such parsers is a good asset to the programmer toolbox. Depending on the complexity of the thing you want to parse, it's a better approach than using regex.

Comment: "Depending on the complexity of the thing you want to parse, it's a better approach than using regex." This is the key sentence here. I agree, that regular expressions are not the right tool for parsing (beyond the recognition of lexical tokens). But your solution is way too complicated for the task at hand. For example why would we need to recognize comments?

Comment: Ah, thank you for your clarification. I adapted a parser that I'm using, and I forgot to remove those rules. They can be removed without problem. You can remove or add more rules as you need, using this example as a template. It properly recognizes numbers, identifiers, reserved words ("and" in this case), and some operators.